# How to pass in a map into UDF in spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Here is my problem, I have a map of `Map[Array[String],String]`, and I want to pass that into a UDF.

Here is my UDF:

```
def lookup(lookupMap:Map[Array[String],String]) = 
  udf((input:Array[String]) => lookupMap.lift(input))
```

And here is my Map variable:

```
val srdd = df.rdd.map { row => (
  Array(row.getString(1),row.getString(5),row.getString(8)).map(_.toString),  
  row.getString(7)
)}
```

Here is how I call the function:

```
val combinedDF  = dftemp.withColumn("a",lookup(lookupMap))(Array($"b",$"c","d"))
```

I first got an error about immutable array, so I changed my array into immutable type, then I got an error about type mismatch. I googled a bit, apparently I can't pass in non-column type directly into a UDF. Can somebody help? Kudos.

---

**Update**: So I did convert everything to a wrapped array. Here is what I did:

```
val srdd = df.rdd.map{row => (WrappedArray.make[String](Array(row.getString(1),row.getString(5),row.getString(8))),row.getString(7))}

val lookupMap = srdd.collectAsMap()


def lookup(lookupMap:Map[collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String],String]) = udf((input:collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => lookupMap.lift(input))


val combinedDF  = dftemp.withColumn("a",lookup(lookupMap))(Array($"b",$"c",$"d"))
```

Now I am having an error like this:

> required: Map[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String],String]
>   -ksh: Map[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String],String]: not found [No such file or directory]

I tried to do something like this:

```
val m = collection.immutable.Map(1->"one",2->"Two")
val n = collection.mutable.Map(m.toSeq: _*)
```

but then I just got back to the error of column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to pass a `Column` as an argument of the UDF; Since you want this argument to be an array, you should use the `array` function in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`, which creates an array Column from a series of other Columns. So the UDF call would be:

```
lookup(lookupMap)(array($"b",$"c",$"d"))
```

Now, since array columns are deserialized into `mutable.WrappedArray`, in order for the map lookup to succeed you'd best make sure that's the type used by your UDF:

```
def lookup(lookupMap: Map[mutable.WrappedArray[String],String]) =
  udf((input: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => lookupMap.lift(input))
```

So altogether:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// Create an RDD[(mutable.WrappedArray[String], String)]:
val srdd = df.rdd.map { row: Row => (
  mutable.WrappedArray.make[String](Array(row.getString(1), row.getString(5), row.getString(8))), 
  row.getString(7)
)}

// collect it into a map (I assume this is what you're doing with srdd...)
val lookupMap: Map[mutable.WrappedArray[String], String] = srdd.collectAsMap()

def lookup(lookupMap: Map[mutable.WrappedArray[String],String]) =
  udf((input: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => lookupMap.lift(input))

val combinedDF  = dftemp.withColumn("a",lookup(lookupMap)(array($"b",$"c",$"d")))
```

Comment: how to you create a wrapped array? I did val srdd = df.rdd.map{row => (WrappedArray(row.getString(1),row.getString(5),row.getString(8)),row.getString(7))} but it's telling me wrapped array doesn't take parameters

Comment: You can use `mutable.WrappedArray.make[String](Array(...))` - see updated answer

Comment: I am getting another error which is    error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.Map[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String],String]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String],String]
pls see my update

Comment: you don't need to use `immutable.Map` - remove imports of `immutable._` or `immutable.Map` if you have any

Comment: Oh, sorry - remove imports/usages of _mutable_ map (`mutable.Map`), you should only use the immutable type.

Comment: These are all my imports: import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,StringType};
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149239/discussion-between-tzach-zohar-and-anna).

Answer (score 1):

Anna your code for srdd/lookupmap is of type org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Array[String], String)]

```
val srdd = df.rdd.map { row => (
Array(row.getString(1),row.getString(5),row.getString(8)).map(_.toString),  
  row.getString(7)
)}
```

Where as in lookup method you are expecting a Map as a parameter

```
def lookup(lookupMap:Map[Array[String],String]) = 
udf((input:Array[String]) => lookupMap.lift(input))
```

That is the reason why you are getting type mismatch error.

First make srdd from RDD[tuple] to a RDD[Map] and then try converting the RDD to Map to resolve this error.

```
val srdd = df.rdd.map { row => Map(
Array(row.getString(1),row.getString(5),row.getString(8)).map(_.toString) ->
  row.getString(7)
)}
```

Comment: hi thanks, but I did this: srdd.collectAsMap(), so I think it is already a map type?

Comment: Yes, I can see now after edit in your post you converted it to Map, but I added my comments based on your old post which did not had srdd as Map.

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram  sir any advice how to handle map in this UDF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas